# Finiteness theorems for profinite groups

Tags: profinite-groups, topological-groups, gr.group-theory, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a profinite group which fits into the following short exact sequence:
$$
1\rightarrow N\rightarrow G \rightarrow K\rightarrow 1
$$
Assume that $N$ is a pro-$p$ group and that $K$ is topologically finitely generated.
Note that $K$ acts naturally by conjugation on $N^{ab}$ and thus we way view $N^{ab}$
as a $\mathbf{Z}_p[[K]]$-module.

Q: If $N^{ab}$ is a finite type $\mathbf{Z}_p[[K]]$-module, does it follow that $G$ is topologically finitely generated?

Comment: Could you please explain what finite type means? 
Generally, $N$ is generated as a normal subgroup of $G$ by a set $X$ if and only if $N/([N,G]N^p)$ is generated by the image of $X$. So if $N^{ab}$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}_p[[K]]$-module, then the answer to your question should be true.

Comment: @Yiftach "finite type" means finitely generated (by a word-by-word translation from French). So you can put your comment as an answer.

Comment: @Yiftach, I think I understand how to do it when the groups are finite. So let $K=<x_1,\ldots,x_r>$ and let $\{n_1,\ldots,n_s\}$ be the generators of the $\mathbf{Z}_p[[K]]$-module. Then by what you said one has that the normal closure of $<x_i*n_j: i,j>$ which I denote by $NC<x_i*n_j: i,j>$ generated $N$. Now if $<x_i*n_j: i,j>$ was contained in a maximal subgroup $M$ of $N$ then because $N$ is a $p$-group we know that $M$ is normal and thus we would have $NC<x_i*n_j: i,j>\subseteq M$ which is a contradiction. 

Comment: @Hugo: the profinite case follows from the finite case (a subgroup is dense iff all its images in finite quotients are surjective; apply this to the normal subgroup generated by a finite subset topologically generating $N$ modulo the commutators).

Comment: PS: by normal here I mean normal in $G$

Comment: @Yves, yes indeed you are right. So may be you (or Yiftach) could write the proof. Is there a natural generalization of this result? It seems to me that the notion of profinite $p$-group is really peculiar and does not seem to generalize easily...  

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here is my comment again with slightly more details. Let $Y$ be a finite subset of $G$ such that its image generates $K$. As I was told by Yves, finite type means finitely generated. Thus, let $X$ be a finite subset of $N$ such that $N^{ab}$ is generated by its image as a $\mathbb{Z}_p[[K]]$-module. Then we claim that $H$ the subgroup generated (topologically) by $X \cup Y$ is equal $G$. Since $Y \subseteq H$ we have that $HN/N \cong K$.

Therefore, $HN=G$. So it suffices to show that $N \leq H$. By definition, the action of $K$ on $N^{ab}$ is via the action of $G$. Since $N$ acts trivially on $N^{ab}$ we have that $H$ action on $N^{ab}$ is the same as $HN=G$ action. Hence, the image of $Y^{H}$ generates $N^{ab}$ as a $\mathbb{Z_p}$-module. So $Y^{H}$ generates $N/\Phi(N)$ as a group, where $\Phi(N)=[N,N]N^{p}$ is the Frattini subgroup of $N$. We deduce that $Y^{H}$ generates $N$ (topologically) and $N \leq H$ as we wanted.

Note that it suffices to ask that $N/([N,N]N^{p})$ (EDIT: see comments below) is finitely generated as a $K$-module.

Comment: I had to break the first paragraph in a strange place since the latx got crazy. 

Comment: at the end you mean $N/([N,N]N^p)$, not $N/([N,K]N^p)$. 

Comment: Yves, you are right. I was trying to be too clever, $[N,K]$ does not necessarily has a meaning as $K$ does not necessarily act on $N$. I think it is possible to replace it by $[N,G]$, but I have to check it to be sure. So I'll leave this to the reader and I will fix my mistake.

Comment: @Yiftach: no you can't, even for a split extension. We can have $N=[N,K]$ then, but $N$ can be huge. For instance, pick $K$ to be cyclic on 2 elements, and $N$ an infinite direct power of a fixed cyclic group of odd order, $K$ acting by $x \mapsto -x$. 

Comment: @Yves: again you are right. I am more confident that it is true if $G$ is pro-$p$. But it is too late to think about it now.

Comment: @Yves, what do you mean by cyclic of 2 elements? You cannot have $N=[N,K]$ if both $N$ and $K$ are pro-$p$, the same as for $p$-groups.

Comment: @Yves: I should add at least if $N$ is reasonably nice, i.e. it has a base for the topology at the identity made of normal subgroups invariant under the $K$ action, for example $N$ is f.g. Otherewise, I will have to think about it.

Comment: @Yiftach: I removed my last comment: I thought at $N$ as pro-$p$, not $G$. The initial question is whether $G$ is finitely generated: if $G$ is pro-$p$, solving this is not a problem.

Comment: @Yves: if $N$ is finitely generated, then of cousre the whole question is trivial. So my example above is trivial. However, the following question is worth thinking of. Is there an example of $N$ and $K$ pro-$p$ groups such that $K$ acts on $N$ and $N=[N,K]$. As I said above $N$ cannot be finitely generated. So the first interesteing case is $N$ an infinite dimension vector space over $\mathbb{F}_p$. 

Comment: @Yiftach: it seems that passing to a finite quotient of the pro-$p$ group $N\rtimes K$ you get a contradiction.

Comment: @Yves: it is nor clear that you could pass to a finite quotient. For that $N$ must have an open subgroup which is invariant under the $K$-action. Why would there always be such a subgroup?

Comment: @Yves: I formulated a question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/98778/when-is-the-semidirect-product-of-profinite-groups-a-profinite-group
